# pandas how to identify strings with specific patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df`,

```
inv_id    
W/E FEB 8 2017
W/E JAN 24 2018
W/E MAR 11 18
W/E APR 09 17
2018 Q1
2011 Q2
```

The values of `inv_id` are all strings. The values have the following formats (`strftime`),

```
%b %d %Y
%b %d %y
%b %d(non zero padded) %Y
%b %d(non zero padded) %y
%Y Q\d(regex decimal)
```

I could not find directive for non zero padded days of a month in `strftime`.

I am wondering how to define patterns and use `pandas` to identify them, maybe `pandas.Series.str.contains`? so the result will look like,

```
inv_id              is_date   
W/E FEB 8 2017      True
W/E JAN 24 2018     True
W/E MAR 11 18       True
W/E APR 09 17       True
2018 Q1             True
2011 Q2             True
```

UPDATE. manage to handle the 2nd case,

```
df['inv_id'].str.contains(pat=r'\b(19|20)\d{2} Q\d{1}\b', regex=True)
```

Comment: Can you use a regex in `pandas.Series.str.contains`?

Comment: @gdlmx https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go completely crazy, use the newer `regex` module and leverage subroutines.
Here, we can first think of simple bricks which are then glued together in a possible format (named `format1`, `format2`, ... `formatn` by me).
See this lovely piece of code:

```
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<month>JAN|FEB|MAR|APR)
   (?<day>\b\d{1,2}\b)
   (?<year>\b[12]\d{3}\b)
   (?<year_short>\b[012]\d\b)
   (?<quarter>Q[1234])
   (?<ws>\s*)

   # here comes the fun part
   (?<format1>(?&month)(?&ws)(?&day)(?&ws)(?:(?&year)|(?&year_short)))
   (?<format2>(?&year)(?&ws)(?&quarter))

   # check for any existance
   (?<formats>(?&format1)|(?&format2))
)
^(?=.*?(?&formats))
```

And [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/heJ6LQ/1/). This needs to be checked via an applied function:

```
def check_format(string):
    if re.search(pattern, string):
        return True
    return False

df['is_date'] = df['inv_id'].apply(check_format)
```

---

In the end you could end up having:

```
import pandas as pd, regex as re
d = {'inv_id': ['W/E FEB 8 2017', 'W/E JAN 24 2018', 'W/E MAR 11 18', 'W/E APR 09 17', '2018 Q1', '2011 Q2', 'somejunk', 'garbage in here']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

rx = re.compile(r'''the pattern from above''', re.VERBOSE)

def check_format(string):
    return True if rx.search(string) else False

df['is_date'] = df['inv_id'].apply(check_format)
print(df)
```

Which would yield

```
            inv_id  is_date
0   W/E FEB 8 2017     True
1  W/E JAN 24 2018     True
2    W/E MAR 11 18     True
3    W/E APR 09 17     True
4          2018 Q1     True
5          2011 Q2     True
6         somejunk    False
7  garbage in here    False
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a sophisticated regular expression.

```
df['is_date'] = df['inv_id'].str.contains('^W/E\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{2,4}$|^\d{4}\s+Q[1-4]$')
```